# Custom email recipient list in Hudson

Tags: hudson

I am using Hudson v2.1.2. to build our code. The build is configured by a shell script (which is clever enough to find the faulty commit that broke the code and the committer's address). 
Is it possible to send email notifications to this address only (rather the spamming the whole development team) ?
I have tried to set an environment variable with this adress and call it from the email list but it does not work...

Any idea ?

Comment: Hudson can email the committer who broke the build.  (And then anyone else who commits before it is fixed.)  But you'd have to let Hudson poll the repository directly and it sounds like you aren't doing that.

Comment: Actually I am. But for some reason, when the build is broken, I do not want to notify the culprit but someone else. To make things clearer: when the build fails I want to email a notification to an email address given 'at run time'.

Comment: Ah.  No.  Hudson doesn't provide that functionality out of the box.  Which means the only way to do this is to edit the Hudson source code itself.  OR you could have your clever shell script sound out the email directly rather than have Hudson do it.  mailx sends mail from the command line of a UNIX/Linux machine.

Comment: OK, I'll look in this direction. Thanks for your help Jeanne.